# Changing App Theme Does NOTHING

Tags: debugging, themes, intellij-13

So say I go into the main.xml (res/layout/main.xml) and go over to the graphical interface, and decide to change my theme from Holo to Holo.Light. It changes in the preview and looks good. I run it, and once it's running, it's Holo. Nothing changes. No errors or anything, it just does nothing. Why? Using IntelliJ 13 and a Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0):

The graphical interface preview what you see for the layout is just to show how it will look in the device. If you just change the Theme there , it won't reflect on the layout xml.

You have to change in the layout or in the manifest for whole application or each activity

Comment: Ah alright, because it's misleading. You'd think if it lets me add controls there that reflect in the XML, it'd work the same with themes. I can't seem to find a theme reference in the XML though? (main or AndroidManifest).

Comment: You can set style="@style/Theme.AppCompat for any view like this in xml

Comment: I'm new to Android and XML.

Comment: I answered to your question - "I can't seem to find a theme reference in the XML though?"

Comment: What? That wasn't even a statement.

Comment: see my updated comment. I answered to your question you asked